# How to infer type from a tuple constructor parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I define a Manager to manage a set of modules, and I want to use a tuple as constructor parameter but the Options of the Constructor is not inferred correctly. Can this be inferred?

```js
export interface Module<Options extends {} = {}> {
  options?: Options;
  activate?: () => void;
  deactivate?: () => void;
}

interface ModuleConstructor<Options> {
  new(...args: any[]): Module<Options>
}


type ModuleDescriptor<
  Ctor extends ModuleConstructor<any>,
  Options = Ctor extends ModuleConstructor<infer O> ? O : never,
> = [
   Ctor, Options
];


class Manager<
  T extends ModuleDescriptor<any>[],
> {
  constructor(descriptors: T) {}
}

class AModule implements Module {
  constructor(public options: {a: number }) {}
}

const flowbase = new Manager([
  [AModule, { a: '1' }], // should emit error but not
]);
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you mean by "correctly" and why the code "should emit error"? You are using a lot of `any` and generic defaults, so `MoudleDescriptor<any>` (spleling error?) is just `[any, unknown]`, to which `[typeof AModule, {a: string}]` is definitely assignable.  Does something like [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Ndj0nW) meet your needs? If so I could maybe write up an answer; if not, please elaborate on what I'm missing (preferably by [edit]ing the question to make the unmet needs clear).

Comment: @jcalz why is it need Intersection when infer the Options in O[I] & {}?

Comment: I’m happy to explain in detail when and if I write up an answer post. Right now the question is whether or not the code meets your needs or if I’m missing something.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks. Yes, it meets. But I have another another related question: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71702772/how-to-infer-type-from-an-tuple-of-constructor-and-its-parameters